# How to identify user created vs. external functions in disassembly

Tags: reverse-engineering

I'm new to assembly and have been playing around with it. While i was analyzing malware, I realised that there are multiple functions named sub_xxxxxx. How does one determine if this sub_xxxxxx is created by a user, or if it is a function that is imported from somewhere else?

Comment: It's not clear to me what you are asking. Most functions are created "automatically" by the compiler when the software is compiled. If a function isn't explicitly compiled from your source code it is usually linked from some library, but those libraries are typically compiled from *some* user's source code. Are you asking how to differentiate library functions like Windows API functions from other functions?

Comment: Yes! I would like to know about the differences between the API and other functions. Are there any indication, to differentiate a API function from other functions?. Thank you for your reply!

Comment: @NightMoon I edited your question to make it more clear; roll it back if that's not what you intended.

Comment: You may also try asking at https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/

Comment: It may be helpful to say what processor this malware is written for, as the answer may vary from processor to processor

Answer (score 1):

If the program is *dynamically linked*, functions are usually pretty easy to identify since you will see imported functions with their correct name. E.g. a user created function will be shown as `sub_xxxxxx`, and `printf` will be shown as `printf`.

However, if the program is *statically linked*, it will be hard to tell the difference between user-created and imported functions. Tools like Ida's [FLIRT](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/q/175/24222) exist to recognize known functions; there may be some free alternatives as well.